# The newest code snippet inclusion tag (in tex.stackexchange site) does NOT preserve the linebreak

Tags: bug, status-completed

Today I notice the code snippet inclusion layout (CSS settings) has been changed in tex.stackexchange site.

I attempted to copy and paste Herbert's (PSTricks maintainer) answer, but the line break be no longer preserved.

Please make a trial by yourself [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/how-to-programmatically-make-tabular-rows-using-whiledo)

Thanks

---

**EDIT 1:**

Can you imagine, what happen if the code contain single line comment (% in tex parlance)?
All the remaining code will be commented out as well :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72911/no-linebreaks-when-copying-syntax-highlighted-code-block-with-ie8

Comment: It is worth informing that even though the status has been completed, this issues still appers on IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using a new TeX prettify plugin from http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/attachmentText?id=115&aid=7911114425991426027&name=lang-latex.js&token=49672000dcf87dff1b1c0bbef0f0ca5c which appears to not contain the same IE8 shattering bug.

Comment: thanks. I am forced to use browsers other than IE now. :) Anyway, IE also renders very slowly in mathjax or jsMath.